# Get permitted triggers with guard conditions in Stateless (.NET state machine library)

Tags: c#, stateless-state-machine

**Background:**

I have same `Trigger` with mutually exclusive `guard` conditions defined with `PermitIf` that will cause transition to different states depending on those conditions.

Guards have `Descriptions` defined and they show up nicely in brackets in exported DOT graph, so it is easy to follow through.

```
machine
   .Configure(Status.Registered)
   .PermitIf(Activity.Submit, Status.Submitted, IsGoodRating, "Is good  rating")
   .PermitIf(Activity.Submit, Status.Denied, IsBadRating, "Is bad rating")
```

Now, I know there is `machine.PermittedTriggers` property that returns allowed Triggers in current state which is great, but here is the question.

**Question :**

Is there a way to get a list of `PermittedTriggers` with corresponding guard conditions for status `Registered` in this case?

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to do this currently, but there's some discussion going on around the possibility of a more complete introspection API here: https://github.com/dotnet-state-machine/stateless/pull/100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could do something like this, but... I don't know how helpful it is:

```
 class Program
{
    enum Status { Registered, Submitted, Denied }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int currentRating = 91;
        RatingTrigger RatingTrigger = new RatingTrigger();

        StateMachine<Status, Trigger> _sm = new StateMachine<Status, Trigger>(Status.Registered);
        _sm.Configure(Status.Registered)
            .PermitIf(RatingTrigger, Status.Submitted, () => RatingTrigger.Guard(currentRating), RatingTrigger.GuardDescription)
            .PermitIf(RatingTrigger, Status.Denied, () => RatingTrigger.Guard(currentRating), RatingTrigger.GuardDescription);

        var list = _sm.PermittedTriggers;

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            if (item.GetType().Equals(typeof(RatingTrigger)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(((RatingTrigger)item).GuardDescription);
            }
            else
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

    }
    private static bool evaluate()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
public abstract class Trigger
{
    public abstract bool Guard(object something);
}
public class RatingTrigger : Trigger
{
    public string GuardDescription = "This Guard evaluaties the current rating. Retuns true if good rating, false if bad rating";
    public override bool Guard(object rating)
    {
         return  (((int)rating) > 90);
    }
}
```